# Binding to a property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a property (MainStudent) in my Page class:

```
public partial class AddStudent : Page
{
    public AddStudent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainStudent = new Student();
    }

    public Student MainStudent
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

What is the best way to bind FirstName property of MainStudent Property (Student Class has some methods. For example: FirstName, LastName.) to Text property of TextBox in XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `Page` has properties that refer only to `Student` you can set its `DataContext` directly there, as last line in your current constructor:

```
this.DataContext = this.MainStudent;
```

and then in XAML do bindings directly to the properties of Student:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FistName}"></TextBox>
```

Or else your can set the DataContext of your `Page` to itself:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

and do bindings like:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MainStudent.FirstName}"></TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MainStudent.Firstname, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: Note that with UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged each Character you type calls the setter. Otherwise the Setter is called on loosing Focus

Comment: It notifies the View that the model is changed thus can update the view. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the following, if the Class containing "MainStudent" is your DataContext
For Example

```
<Grid DataContext="{StaticRessource YourViewModelDefinedInRessources}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding MainStudent.FirstName}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding MainStudent.LastName}" />
</Grid>
```

If you need further help just ask ;)